# SQL: Updating row within loop

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to remove the first character in LastNames that start with a space. The code below seems to clear LastName entirely, making the field empty. Do you see something wrong?

```
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @LastName NVARCHAR(255)

while (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE LastName LIKE ' %') > 0
Begin

    Select Top 1 @Id = Id, @LastName = LastName FROM [Table] WHERE LastName LIKE ' %'
    UPDATE [Table] SET LastName = SUBSTRING(@LastName, 1, LEN(@LastName)) WHERE Id = @Id
End
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the code you posted runs in an infinite loop.

`LastName = SUBSTRING(LastName, 1, LEN(LastName))` will have no effect other than removing right trailing space (as that is not counted by `LEN`). To remove the left most character you would need `SUBSTRING(LastName, 2, LEN(LastName) - 1)`.

But, you don't need a RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row) loop here just use

```
UPDATE [Table]
SET LastName = LTRIM(LastName) 
WHERE LastName  LIKE ' %'
```

to update all matching rows in a set based way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you're using a LIKE '°%' statement in the SELECT statement, while restricting.
Next to that, you should avoid executing queries inside a loop, since that will hurt performance badly.

SQL is set based , so it is perfectly possible to execute this code without using a loop.

```
UPDATE [Table]
SET LastName = LTRIM(LastName)
WHERE LastName LIKE ' %'
```

Comment: `LTRIM` is needed here. The OP's code will process the same row multiple times if it has more than one leading space (and `LastName = SUBSTRING(LastName, 1 LEN(LastName)` will not have the desired effect anyway)